# Como sair do controller antes de chegar ao final com Vraptor 3?

Tags: java, vraptor

Tem algum comando no vraptor 3 que faça sair do controller antes de chegar no final dele?
 Pois tenho um controller que caso aconteça um determinado 
 processo no meio dele ele retornará um json de erro, e preciso que não dê mais continuidade no código.

Segue Exemplo abaixo:

```
 @Path("/metogo)
 public void Metodo(Teste teste) {

  if( aconteceAlgo  ){
     result.use(json()).indented().from(objErro).serialize();
     // Sair do controller e não continuar todo processo abaixo.
  }
  // continua o processo no Controller  
 }
```

OBS: não irei fazer um redirect para nenhuma outra pagina, apenas retornar JSON

Answer (score 1):

Se uma método retorna void, você pode encerrar a execução dele usando a palavra **return**;

```
@Path("/metogo)
public void Metodo(Teste teste) {
    //...
    if (aconteceAlgo) {
        result.use(json()).indented().from(objErro).serialize();
        return; // <------------------
    }
    // continua o processo no Controller ...
}
```